# Run without blocking

Tags: twisted

I'm new to twisted and programming, I'm making a multiplayer game, and what i need the client to do is send the location of the player to the server and retrieve the location of the opponent, but when I run the reactor it gets stuck in the loop checking for events, what I want it to do is get and send data and then continue to run the game loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do just about the same thing as is done by [Game](http://launchpad.net/game).  Importantly, you don't want to "run the reactor ... and then continue to run the game loop".  You want the reactor and the game loop running in tandem.  In particular, take a look at this [go](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~game-hackers/game/trunk/annotate/head:/game/view.py#L327) method, where a 100Hz rendering loop and a 25Hz input handling loop are set up, and this [start](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~game-hackers/game/trunk/annotate/head:/game/environment.py#L60) method where a model simulation loop is set up.

These loops can all run because they use the reactor's scheduling APIs, and since they run while the reactor is running, network events can be handled at the same time as well.